Call to a member function getFormattedAddress() on string in vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php
I am getting Call to a member function getFormattedAddress() on string in vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php error with following code.
if ($sendingDays === $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PROP_LAST_DAY_REMINDER, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)) {

    $emailTemplateId = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PROP_FINAL_RENEWAL_TEST_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
} else {
    $emailTemplateId = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PROP_RENEWAL_TEST_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
}

$sender = [
    'name' => $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PROP_CONFIG_ADMIN_FROM_NAME, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE),
    'email' => $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PROP_CONFIG_ADMIN_FROM_EMAIL, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)
];

$data = [
    'firstname' => $renewData['firstname'],
    'lastname' => $renewData['lastname'],
    'renewalurl' => $renewalUrl,
    'sendingdays' => $sendingDays,
    'store' => $renewData['store_name'],
    'propUrl' => $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl() . 'prop'
];

$renewalEmailAttempt += 1;
try {
    $transport = $this->transportBuilder
        ->setTemplateIdentifier($emailTemplateId)
        ->setTemplateOptions([
                                 'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                                 'store' => $storeId
                             ])
        ->setTemplateVars($data)
        ->setFromByScope($sender, $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
        ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PROP_RENEWAL_TEST_MODE, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)
                    ? $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PROP_RENEWAL_TEST_EMAIL_RECEPIENT, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)
                    : $emailAddress)
        ->getTransport();

    $transport->sendMessage();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->_logger->error('Error sending  renewal emails: ' . $renewData['id'] . ' ' . $e->getMessage());
}


I was getting this error because I was passing plane array in to the
->setTemplateVars($data)

code. When I converted in to Object and passed to setTemplateVars(), the issue got fixed.
if ($sendingDays === $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PROP_LAST_DAY_REMINDER, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)) {

    $emailTemplateId = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PROP_FINAL_RENEWAL_TEST_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
} else {
    $emailTemplateId = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PROP_RENEWAL_TEST_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
}

$sender = [
    'name' => $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PROP_CONFIG_ADMIN_FROM_NAME, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE),
    'email' => $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PROP_CONFIG_ADMIN_FROM_EMAIL, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)
];

$data = [
    'firstname' => $renewData['firstname'],
    'lastname' => $renewData['lastname'],
    'renewalurl' => $renewalUrl,
    'sendingdays' => $sendingDays,
    'store' => $renewData['store_name'],
    'propUrl' => $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl() . 'prop'
];

$postObject = new DataObject();
$postObject->setData($data);

$renewalEmailAttempt += 1;
try {
    $transport = $this->transportBuilder
        ->setTemplateIdentifier($emailTemplateId)
        ->setTemplateOptions([
                                 'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                                 'store' => $storeId
                             ])
        ->setTemplateVars(['prop' => $postObject])
        ->setFromByScope($sender, $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
        ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PROP_RENEWAL_TEST_MODE, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)
                    ? $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PROP_RENEWAL_TEST_EMAIL_RECEPIENT, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)
                    : $emailAddress)
        ->getTransport();

    $transport->sendMessage();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
}
    $this->_logger->error('Error sending  renewal emails: ' . $renewData['id'] . ' ' . $e->getMessage());

I had to use code like.
$postObject = new DataObject();
$postObject->setData($data);

and
->setTemplateVars(['prop' => $postObject])
